# How to display image data returned from dreambooth / stable-diffusion model?

Tags: javascript, python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I'm querying a dreambooth model from Hugging Face using the inference API and am getting a huge data response string back which starts with: `����çx00çx10JFIFçx00çx01çx01çx00çx00çx01çx0`...

Content-type is: image/jpeg

How do I decode this and display it as an image in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I suppose something similar to that should do it.

```js
for (var e = atob("����çx00çx10JFIFçx00çx01çx01çx00çx00çx01çx0..."), t = new Array(e.length), r = 0; r < e.length; r++) t[r] = e.charCodeAt(r);
var n = new Uint8Array(t),
    a = new Blob([n], {
        type: "image/jpeg"
    }),
    x = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(a);

let img = document.createElement("img")

img.src = x;
```

Comment: tried this and getting: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`

Answer (score 0):

got it working by including a responseType param in the axios request.

Node.js code:

```
const inputData = {
    inputs: prompt,
    options: {
        wait_for_model: true,
    },
}

const response = await axios({
    url: `https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/${model}`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.HUGGING_FACE_TOKEN}`,
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
})

const mimeType = response.headers['content-type']

const result = response.data

const base64data = Buffer.from(result).toString('base64')

const img = `data:${mimeType};base64,` + base64data

return img
```

React code:

```
<img src={img} />
```

Comment: The image's response type is application/json which is making it unusable in my project. Is there a way to convert this into an image since it does not seem like the API is returning an image?

Comment: Hey cormac! I'm having some issues setting up HuggingFace Inference API, any chance you could assist?

Comment: @RoiMulia yea sure! Are you trying to call a public repo?

Comment: Hey @cormacncheese, thank you for the fast response! Yes, I am. Maybe you can do some paid-consultant to my company regarding the subject? I can send you all the info via the e-mail.